# Validating a WCF Service on startup

Tags: c#, iis, wcf

Have a WCF service, hosted in IIS, and I want to verify that the configuration settings are valid, e.g. the logging directory exists or can be created.  If the configuration fails, I want to consider the service invalid, and notify via event log, etc.  Ideally the service would be unavailable if invalid.

If I hosted as a windows service, I could do this easily.  But hosted in IIS?  I don't know of a good way to make the service unavailable from code.

Any ideas?  If it helps, the WCF Service runs in its own app pool.

TIA!
James

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you throw an exception the service will not be available.  So in your service's constructor do your checks and if everything is perfect and if its not throw an exception and the service will not be there.  If remote errors are off then browsing to the service will show the error and stack trace.

Comment: It does indeed behave that way.  Still trying to figure out how to handle the scenario on the client side

Answer (score 2):

Other posters have suggested throwing from your service's constructor. This approach will work fine, but a potentially better approach would be to implement a custom ServiceHostFactory (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa702697.aspx) and do the validation in the CreateServiceHost method. The advantage to doing so would be that your validation error would become part of the "The service could not be activated" error reporting & HTML page.

Answer (score 0):

Have a private method in the service called test which will return boolean false, if the either loggigng directory does not exist or cannot be created etc..

Call this test method from constructor of the service. If the method returns false, send a clear information that the service is down.